# remove outertag from spyne wsdl input and output

Tags: wsdl, spyne

I am using spyne for creating my webservice.

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [

    url(
        r'^InventoryService.wsdl', DjangoView.as_view(
            name="InventoryService",
            services=[InventoryService],
            tns='InventoryService',
            in_protocol=Soap12(validator='lxml'),
            out_protocol=Soap12(),
            cache_wsdl=False
        )
    ),
]
```

views.py

```
#views.py 
spyne.const.RESULT_SUFFIX =''
spyne.const.REQUEST_SUFFIX ='Request'

class GetFilterValuesRequest(ComplexModel):
    id = String(min_occurs=1, max_length=64, nillable=False)
    password = String(min_occurs=0, max_length=64, nillable=False)
    productId = String(min_occurs=1, max_length=64, nillable=False)

class FilterValues(ComplexModel):
    productId = String(min_occurs=1, max_length=64, default='55', nillable=False)

class InventoryService(Service):

    @rpc(GetFilterValuesRequest, _returns=FilterValues, )
    def getFilterValues(ctx, GetFilterValuesRequest):
        return FilterValues(productId='33', )
```

I want to remove the outer "GetFilterValuesRequest" from the input and update "getFilterValues" in output response to "FilterValues".

I will add my current input and output also my expected input and output.

Following is the current input and output when I call this request through soapui

```
#Current input
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:inv="InventoryService" xmlns:core="core.views">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <inv:getFilterValuesRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <inv:GetFilterValuesRequest>
            <core:id>?</core:id>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <core:password>?</core:password>
            <core:productId>?</core:productId>
         </inv:GetFilterValuesRequest>
      </inv:getFilterValuesRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

#Current output
<soap12env:Envelope xmlns:soap12env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tns="InventoryService" xmlns:s0="core.views">
   <soap12env:Body>
      <tns:getFilterValuesResponse>
         <tns:getFilterValues>
            <s0:productId>33</s0:productId>
         </tns:getFilterValues>
      </tns:getFilterValuesResponse>
   </soap12env:Body>
</soap12env:Envelope>
```

Following is my expected output in soap ui.

```
#Expected input 

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:inv="InventoryService" xmlns:core="core.views">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
         <inv:GetFilterValuesRequest>
            <core:id>?</core:id>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <core:password>?</core:password>
            <core:productId>?</core:productId>
         </inv:GetFilterValuesRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


#Expected output

<soap12env:Envelope xmlns:soap12env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tns="InventoryService" xmlns:s0="core.views">
   <soap12env:Body>
      <tns:GetFilterValuesResponse>
         <tns:FilterValues>
            <s0:productId>33</s0:productId>
         </tns:FilterValues>
      </tns:GetFilterValuesResponse>
   </soap12env:Body>
</soap12env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
@rpc(GetFilterValuesRequest, _returns=FilterValues,_body_style = "bare" )
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.